# Success callback Emscripten FETCH API in C++ class

Tags: c++, fetch-api, webassembly, emscripten

I am working with WebAssembly and try to make an HTTPS request from C++. I have seen the solution of [Emscripten FETCH API](https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/fetch.html) and tried to use it.

To test it, I created a `Test` class where I send the request like this :

```
void Test::sendRequest() {
    emscripten_fetch_attr_t attr;
    emscripten_fetch_attr_init(&attr);
    strcpy(attr.requestMethod, "GET");
    attr.attributes = EMSCRIPTEN_FETCH_LOAD_TO_MEMORY;
    attr.onsuccess = &Test::onSuccess;
    attr.onerror = &Test::onError;
    emscripten_fetch(&attr, "http://127.0.0.1:5000/");
}
```

And my onSuccess callback look like this :

```
void Test::onSuccess(struct emscripten_fetch_t *fetch) {
    printf("Finished downloading %llu bytes from URL %s.\n", fetch->numBytes, fetch->url);
    setText(QString::fromUtf8(fetch->data));
    emscripten_fetch_close(fetch); // Free data associated with the fetch.
}
```

But, when I try to compile I have an error saying :

```
error: assigning to 'void (*)(struct emscripten_fetch_t *)' from incompatible type 'void
  (Test::*)(struct emscripten_fetch_t *)'
attr.onsuccess = &Test::onSuccess;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It seems that I can't put the callback function in the class, but I need to access the class in order to modify the text attribute of the instance with the response.

I tried to define the Test class with the Singleton pattern and to remove the callback function from the class. With this method I can modify the text attribute getting the unique instance of the class but I would like to put callback function in the class directly if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use a non-static member function as a callback directly.

However, most callback interfaces have a "user data" field somewhere for communicating back to the originator.

`emscripten_fetch_attr_t` has a `void* userData` member where you can store any pointer you want.
This pointer is passed as `userData` in the argument to the callbacks, and you just need to cast it back to the correct type.

So you can use a free function as a wrapping callback, with the object as "user data":

```
void onSuccess(struct emscripten_fetch_t *fetch) {
    auto test = static_cast<Test*>(fetch->userData);
    test->onSuccess(fetch);
}

void Test::sendRequest() {
    emscripten_fetch_attr_t attr;
    emscripten_fetch_attr_init(&attr);
    strcpy(attr.requestMethod, "GET");
    attr.attributes = EMSCRIPTEN_FETCH_LOAD_TO_MEMORY;
    attr.userData = this;
    attr.onsuccess = onSuccess;
    // ...
```

And make sure that the object is alive when the callback fires.